# I am trying to figure out how I can have my dropdown items be displayed over other content

Tags: css, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I have created a dropdown menu button when it's clicked it displays the dropdown items but I was the dropdown contents to be displayed over my other content but instead they are displayed beneath my other content and I would like to know how I can achieve this. The images I currently have are displayed over the dropdown items.

my code:

```
const LightMode = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() =>{
        axios.get('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all').then(res=>{
            let toInsert = res.data.map((country) =>({
                name: country.name.common,
                population: country.population,
                region: country.region,
                capital: country.capital,
                image: country.flags.png
            }))

            setData((prev) => [...prev, ...toInsert])
        })
    }, [])

    console.log(data)
    return(
        <div className='lightmode-content'>
            <NavigationBar />
            <div className='search-dropdown'>
                <input type='text' className='search-input' placeholder='Search'/>
                <div className='dropdown'>
                    <button className='dropdown-button' onClick={() => setIsPressed(!isPressed)}>
                        <span>Filter by Region</span>    
                    </button> 
                    {isPressed ? 
                        <div className='dropdown-items'>
                            <a className='dropdown-item' href='#'>Africa</a>
                            <a className='dropdown-item' href='#'>America</a>
                            <a className='dropdown-item' href='#'>Asia</a>
                            <a className='dropdown-item' href='#'>Europe</a>
                            <a className='dropdown-item' href='#'>Oceania</a>
                        </div>: null
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='grid-box'>
                {data ? data.map((country, idx) =>(
                    <Card className='country-card' key={idx}>
                        <Card.Img src={country.image} style={{height: '175px'}}/>
                        <Card.Title style={{textAlign:'center'}}>{country.name}</Card.Title>
                        <Card.Body>
                            <div>
                                <span className='body-text'>Population:</span> {country.population.toLocaleString(undefined)}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <span className='body-text'>Region:</span> {country.region}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <span className='body-text'>Capital:</span> {country.capital}
                            </div>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                )) : null}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and my CSS file:

```
.lightmode-content{
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.search-dropdown{
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6%;
}

.grid-box{
    position: absolute;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    top: 20%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px;
}

.country-card{
    margin: 30px;
}

.body-text{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.search-input{
    margin-left: 5%;
    border: none;
}

.dropdown {
    margin-right: 5%;
    height: 6%;
    position: relative;
}
  
.dropdown-button{
    border: none;
    width: 200px;
}

.dropdown-button:hover{
    background-color: rgb(207, 207, 207);
}

.dropdown-items{
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-item:hover{
    background-color: rgb(207, 207, 207);
}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try add z-index:9 (or higher ex.99) to your drop-down block.
It's should move your drop-down content at higher layer

```
.search-dropdown {
   z-index:9;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works! what exactly is z-index if you don't mind me asking? it's the first time Ive seen that

Comment: Sure!
The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky) and flex items (elements that are direct children of display:flex elements).